# Application:OpenFile Not Called After Splash Screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am experimenting with macOS xcode objective-C file handling - or having my app open files of a specific extension.

So far, I have used [this doc to register file types](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html) (even though iOS and I'm using Mac, same process it seems) and that worked perfectly. That associates file extensions with my app and allows double-clicking of the files to launch my app.

Now I want to add handling of the file once it opens. I created a new Cocoa NSObject Subclass called FileOpen.

In my MainMenu.xib I created an Object (Blue Cube) and changed the class to FileOpen. I set it as delegate to File Owner. This was described [in the selected answer to this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921407/applicationdidfinishlaunching-not-invoked)

Now, in FileOpen.m I have this - just to basically show a NSAlert when the file is opened:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
NSLog(@"Application Finished Launching");
}

-(BOOL)application:(NSApplication*)sharedApplication openFile:(NSString*) fileName
{
[[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Opening File"
defaultButton:@"OK"
alternateButton:nil
otherButton:nil
informativeTextWithFormat:@"Testing file opening handle code."] runModal];
return;
}
```

This all seems to work fine. If I run my app, I get the NSLog that the application finished launching. If I double-click a file, it runs the app and gives the NSAlert.

The problem I am running into is that my app has a splash screen. This shows until the user closes it and then the main app starts. If I disable my splash screen, the above all works fine as described. If I enable my splash screen, the NSLog saying application finished launching does run, after the splash screen, but then the application:openfile never runs (and no NSAlert).

I assume I need to add some code that waits for applicationWillFinishLaunching before running the
application:open file? Is there a way to wait until the application is fully initialized to be able to open/handle the file correctly? It seems that by having a splash screen is interrupting the application:openfile

Comment: Note that the application delegate method `applicationWillFinishLaunching` is called just _before_ the application object is initialized, while `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called _after_ the application has been launched and initialized.

Comment: Thank you for this red_menace - but this isn't really the issue. The issue I am having is application:openFile does not run if my app shows a splash screen first (a simple NSWindow). If I disable the splash screen, then it does run and displays the NSAlert - so the question is more: How can I wait until app fully starts (re: splash screen is closed and applicationWillFinishLaunching runs) to be able to open/handle the file correctly. It seems that by having a splash screen interrupts the application:openfile.

Comment: Yes.  You are blocking the app before it has a chance to finish launching.  You might try showing your splash screen in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` (giving the app a chance to launch), stashing any files passed to `application:openFiles` (it is called after `applicationWillFinishLaunching`) in an instance variable until the dialog is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to red_menace I was able to get this working. The key was moving the handling of my splash screen to the NSObject Subclass FileOpen. I did this by just adding a notification to open the splash screen in the FileOpen class instead of where it was originally invoked (the main view).

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillFinishLaunching");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"WhatsNewOpen" object:self];
}

-(BOOL)application:(NSApplication*)sharedApplication openFile:(NSString*) fileName
{
    
    [[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Opening Files"
    defaultButton:@"OK"
    alternateButton:nil
    otherButton:nil
    informativeTextWithFormat:@"Testing File Open"] runModal];
    return;

}
```